# Usage of Prepositions at the end of sentences

Tags: prepositions, infinitives

> 1. This is not a safe place **to live.**
> 2. This is not a safe place **to live in.**

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences? Why prepositions are used at the end of some sentences like sentence 2 or “he gave me a pen **to write with**.”?

Comment: For the same reason that we don't just write *this is not a safe place*. (Why bother with *to live*?) Additional words add additional meaning or nuance.

Answer (score 2):

> When the antecedent is **'place'**, 'in' is optional. But in this case, if we drop the preposition, the sentence sounds good.

*"This is not a safe place to live."* (= This is not a safe place where you live).

*"This is not a safe place to live in."* (= This is not a safe place in which you live / which you live in.)

> When the antecedent is another noun (NOT, *'Place'*), you cannot drop the preposition 'in' :

*"This is not a safe city to live in."* ✔

*"This is not a safe city to live."* ✖

Comment: I do not think both the sentences are different. I think one can easily live without 'in' at the end.

Comment: In my English, _This is not a safe city to live_ is odd, and I can't imagine saying it.

Comment: "to live" seems temporal in this context whereas the sentence as a whole seems geographical, "to live in" seems more geographical